# WordPress custom taxonomy not showing

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

I have a simple custom Taxonomy

```
  register_taxonomy( 'categories', array('career'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Departments',
        'singular_label' => 'Department',
    )
);
```

and I am trying show a list of the Taxonomy like so ..

```
   $terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'career',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
        </a><?php
    }
}
?>
```

yet nothing is displaying, I have been over and over for a few hours and cant see the problem, can anyone see why this is not displaying ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'career',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);
```

Your taxonomy isn't called `career`. Your taxonomy is called (confusingly) `categories`.

If you check [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/), you'll see the second argument passed to `register_taxonomy` is the object type (eg, `post`, `my_cpt`) that the tax is to be used on. So in your registration you are creating a taxonomy called `categories` that will be used on the `career` post type.

Comment: so near yet so far.. thank you for your help, this one was so simple yet i missed it. also thanks for the explanation, i was a bit confused what both arguments were for.